# Css styling html embedded code

Tags: html, css, embed, stylesheet

When I embed a piece of html code, it seems that it won't be effected by the linked css file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>worldmapper BETA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <embed type="text/html" src="test.html">

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. `<embed>` acts like `<iframe>` (just not so well defined, so you should use `<iframe>` instead).

You are loading a separate document in a sub-window.

For the CSS to apply, you need to link the CSS to that document.

---

Consider using a template system which you apply either server side or at build time instead. Then your single web page will consist of a single HTML document.

Comment: So using <iframe> is the solution?

Comment: No. I said that `<embed>` acts like an `<iframe>`. You'll experience the same limitation.

Comment: Oh ok I get it, I'll have to use a server site in order to use this method where I build one file out of different files...